# Why are there more complex than smooth structures?

Tags: differential-geometry

I've read that given a topological manifold, there are only finitely many smooth structures on it (except for dimension 4) but many more (even uncountably many) complex structures. But doesnt this statement contradict intuition since every complex manifold of dimension $n$ is automatically a smooth manifold in dimension $2n$? I apologize for the shallowness of the question but i really want to start to build some inuition for different structures and i am not totally sure how to. If you can give me exercises to build the right intuition in this direction or some elementary references, i would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every complex manifold of dimension $n$ is automatically a smooth manifold of dimension $2n$, but different complex manifolds can have the same underlying smooth manifold. That is, the map on isomorphism classes can have large fibers, and in particular is not injective. (It is also not surjective.)

Being a complex manifold is extra *structure* on a smooth manifold; it is not just a property. That is, the relationship between complex and smooth manifolds is like the relationship between groups and sets, not like the relationship between abelian groups and groups. Every group is either abelian or it's not, but a set can be equipped with the extra structure of a group in many ways: for example, the set with $4$ elements can be $\mathbb{Z}_4$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

A standard example is $S^1 \times S^1$; complex structures on this correspond to elliptic curves (up to a choice of basepoint) and there are uncountably many of these. More generally, see [moduli spaces of algebraic curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_of_algebraic_curves).

Comment: Thank you, i should be more careful about the distinction of property and extra structure. Is it difficult to answer how many different smooth structures there are e.g. on the torus? And do all elliptic curves underly the same smooth manifold? (i hope this question makes some sense..)

Comment: @Mekanik: in dimensions less than or equal to $3$ classical results imply that every topological manifold has a unique smooth structure. And yes, all elliptic curves are diffeomorphic to $S^1 \times S^1$ as smooth manifolds.